# How to scan characters in strings to flag if the match is correct

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, knime

I have 2 columns of strings and I'd like to create a column with a "yes" or "no" if the first 3 characters of each string in their row match. Basically code that goes over the first 3 characters of column 1 row 1 and compares it with column 2 row 1 to see if the first 3 chars match; if yes then it should print YES in column 3 as seen in the example.

IE: Row 1 Column 1 scans "p""a""s" and looks in  Row 1 Column 2 and scans "p""a""s" meanign that they are the same and should be true in Column 3.

I'm fairly new to python; my apologies.

Original Table:

```
+-------------+---------+----------+
|  Row Index  |  Col1   |  Col2    |
+-------------+---------+----------+
| 1           | pasta   | pastas   |
| 2           | sauces  | orange   |
| 3           | kiwi    | kiwis    |
+-------------+---------+----------+
```

Expected Output Table:

```
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+
|  Row Index  |  Col1   |  Col2    |  Col3   |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+
| 1           | pasta   | pastas   |  YES    |
| 2           | sauces  | orange   |  NO     |
| 3           | rosin   | robert   |  NO     |
+-------------+---------+----------+---------+
```

I don't have any code to show as I'm not sure how to start this. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one-liner:

```
df['Col3'] = (df['Col1'].str[:3] == df['Col2'].str[:3]).map(
    {True: 'YES', False: 'NO'})
```

Rule of thumb: pretty much everything you do with pandas/numpy data is better in vector format, i.e. without using loops.

Step1: extract first three letters from all strings in a column:
You can perform pretty much all standard string operations on columns via `df['col'].str` objects. Here: `df['Col1'].str[:3]`

Step2: check if 3-char prefixes match: again, you can directly compare columns to get a column of boolean values. `df['Col1'].str[:3] == df['Col2'].str[:3]`

Step3: replace boolean values with 'YES' and 'NO'. I hope you see where it is going: `boolean_data.map({True: 'YES', False: 'NO'})`

Comment: I would also convert column types to `str` first. Basically df['Col1'].astype(str).str[:3]